# How to combine conditions with several selector?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hy, I'm trying to combine these condition:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($('#box2').isOnScreen() == true){
        $('#box2').css('opacity', '1')}
else{$('#box2').css('opacity', '0')};
        });

$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($('#box3').isOnScreen() == true){
        $('#box3').css('opacity', '1')}
else{$('#box3').css('opacity', '0')};
        });
```

I tried something like that:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($('.box').isOnScreen() == true){
            $(this).css('opacity', '1')}
    else{$(this).css('opacity', '0')};
            });
```

but it don't work

my html look likes this

```
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are the `#b2` and `#b3` elements in your HTML?

Comment: Into a div #container on the body?

Comment: oups sorry it's a mistake it's #box3 #box2 not #b2 #b3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need jquery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method

```
$('.box').each(function(){
    if ($(this).isOnScreen() == true){
        $(this).css('opacity', '1')
    } else{
        $(this).css('opacity', '0')};
    }
});
```

Something like this, should do the trick.